# Set up an environment with multiple counters

Tags: counters, newtheorem

I am writing solutions for a textbook and the exercises are labelled as [chapter].[section].[exercise] (ex: 6.4.32 would be exercise 32 from section 4 of chapter 6). How do I create a theorem environment with this numbering scheme?

So far I have:

```
\newcounter{chapter}
\addtocounter{chapter}{6}

\newcounter{section}
\addtocoutner{4}

\newcounter{exercise}
\addtocounter{exercise}{32}
```

and the theorem environments:

```
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{exrc}{Exercise}[chapter]
\newtheorem{soln}{Solution}[chapter]
\newtheorem{ans}{Answer}[chapter]
```

But of course this only provides me with the correct chapter numbering, completely ignores the section number, and assumes each exercise directly proceeds the one before, starting at 1 (which is almost never the case for my purposes).

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Why  not `\newtheorem{exrc}{Exercise}[section]`, and so on?

Comment: you should define section to be under chapter, subsection to be under section etc and then finally your theorems to be under subsubsection  see for example `report` class which defines `\newcounter {chapter}
\newcounter {section}[chapter]
\newcounter {subsection}[section]
\newcounter {subsubsection}[subsection]
\newcounter {paragraph}[subsubsection]
\newcounter {subparagraph}[paragraph]
`